# Setting UITabBarViewController as the root view?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6

If I create a `UITabBarController` in `storyboard` and set `is Initial View Controller` to yes, does that make it the `rootViewController` for my application? I read the following from the Apple documentation:

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the
>   UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that
>   is accessible through the view property. **When deploying a tab bar
>   interface, you must install this view as the root of your window.**
>   Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be
>   installed as a child of another view controller.

I am currently setting `is Initial View Controller` to yes in `storyboard` for my `UITabBarController` and I am not explicitly setting it as the `root` of the `window` in my `AppDelegate`. Everything seems to work fine, but I am receiving the following error 3 times:

> Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should
>   use the smoother single-stage animation.

Is this error related to the fact that I am not setting the `UITabBarController` as the `root view` of the application window?

Comment: No, that's not the cause of your error. Making the tab bar controller the initial view controller, does set it as the window's root view controller. Are you adding any code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:?

Comment: @rdelmar No, I did not touch `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. I have only added the `UITabBarController` and set it as the `initial view controller` for the application.

Comment: So what else have you done? Are you doing any animations. Please explain what sequence of events leads to the warnings.

Comment: I created a new single view application project in Xcode 6.0.1, set the deployment target to 7.0, deleted the view controller in storyboard and placed a UITabBarController there, created a subclass of UITabBarController, then went back to storyboard to enter my subclass of UITabBarController into the controller, finally I set is initial view controller to yes. That is all, there are no animations.

Comment: I duplicated what you said you did, and I get no errors.

Comment: @rdelmar I ran it in simulator and didn't receive the errors. I only receive them when I run in on my device. I will continue searching for the solution. Thanks for the help)